# Can celery gracefully endure a mongodb failover when using it as a broker?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, replication, celery

I'm using a mongodb replica set both as a broker and result storage for celery.

I have successfully got it running against the replica set, but when I take down the primary mongodb node, and the replica set promotes secondary to primary, the celery worker and beat processes simply die.

If I restart them, they run just fine with the new primary. Is there a way to get celery to wait a few moments for the new primary to be elected?

celery is being run under django-celery in this case.

UPDATE Logged issue to kombu (the transport layer employed by celery): https://github.com/ask/kombu/issues/123

Comment: Might want to post to Celery's issue tracker: https://github.com/ask/celery/issues

Comment: Yeah, I expect I will (guess I should just do it now). I just wanted to give the benefit of the doubt and ensure I didn't miss something.

Comment: Logged, and updated the question with a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a "mongos" instance as a wrapper over your replica set. It's not a point of failure in your case. And "mongos" will take care of failover.